# How to use ng-animate in angular 1.2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

### Base

angular 1.1.5 - http://plnkr.co/edit/eoKt8o4MJw9sWdYdeG3s?p=preview - WORKS

### Upped

angular 1.2.6 - http://plnkr.co/edit/WopgAtFNVm1mKf5Li99h?p=preview - FAIL

---

I think I did follow the instructions from the docs - http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate

> • First include angular-animate.js in your HTML
>
> • Then load the module in your application by adding it as a dependent module

It's quite late in my timezone and I probably miss something obvious. My guess would be - CSS file between 1.1.5 and 1.2.6 is not compatible? Cannot really tell...

Anyway here is the code form **upped** plunker, I included some comments to emphasise that I followed instructions from docs:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Top Animation</title>
  <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.6/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <!-- ^^^ load animate -->
</head>

<script>
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']); // <-- dependent module

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.names = ['Igor Minar', 'Brad Green', 'Dave Geddes', 'Naomi Black', 'Greg Weber', 'Dean Sofer', 'Wes Alvaro', 'John Scott', 'Daniel Nadasi'];
});

</script>

<body ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div class="well" style="margin-top: 30px; width: 200px; overflow: hidden;">
    <form class="form-search"> 
        <div class="input-append">
          <input type="text" ng-model="search" class="search-query" style="width: 80px">
          <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
          <li ng-animate="'animate'" ng-repeat="name in names | filter:search">
            <a href="#"> {{name}} </a>
          </li> 
      </ul>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### Many thanks for help!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Here is a working version of your plunker...  http://plnkr.co/edit/05irGvYwD4y9ZRb1ZHSw?p=preview

In Angular 1.2+, you don't need to declare the ng-animate directive anymore. Animations can be added with css alone. So for your example, you can remove the ng-animate directive and give the element a css class, so change...

```
<li ng-animate="'animate'" ng-repeat="name in names | filter:search">

to...

<li class="animate" ng-repeat="name in names | filter:search">
```

and then update your css to ...

```
.animate.ng-enter, 
.animate.ng-leave
{ 
...

.animate.ng-leave.animate.ng-leave-active,
.animate.ng-enter {
...

.animate.ng-enter.ng-enter-active, 
.animate.ng-leave {
...
```

Angular will simply add the ng-enter, ng-hide, ng-leave.. etc. classes to the element and remove them appropriately during the animation lifecycle, which will trigger the css animations. There is a list of which directives support which animation classes in the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) under 'Usage'. In this example, we are animating ng-repeat, so the ng-enter, ng-leave and ng-move classes will be added to our element at the appropriate time and we can attach animations to them with css.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm... I should have mentioned that http://www.nganimate.org/ refers to 1.1.5 at the moment - I find it exciting to work on technology that is evolving so quickly!

Comment: A single up-vote is not enough to express my appreciation. Somehow this answer was surprisingly hard to find, given the wealth of examples out there with old information. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've found this demo that does a great job:
http://jsbin.com/usaruce/3/edit

It uses following syntax:

```
.todo-item {
  -webkit-transition: color 0.6s, background-color 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: color 0.6s, background-color 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: color 0.6s, background-color 0.3s;
  transition: color 0.6s, background-color 0.3s;
}
.todo-item.ng-enter {
  -webkit-animation: fadeInLeft 1s;
  -moz-animation: fadeInLeft 1s;
  -ms-animation: fadeInLeft 1s;
  animation: fadeInLeft 1s;
}
.todo-item.ng-leave {
  -webkit-animation: bounceOut 1s;
  -moz-animation: bounceOut 1s;
  -ms-animation: bounceOut 1s;
  animation: bounceOut 1s;
}
```

It also takes advantage of [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) *(fadeInLeft, bounceOut)*