# How can I animate the movement of remaining ng-repeat items when one is removed?

Tags: angularjs, css, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-animate

I have a dynamic list of items using ng-repeat. When something happens an item may disappear. I have handled smoothly animating the removal of these items using ng-animate, but after they are gone, the remaining items simply snap to their new position. How can I animate this movement smoothly?

I've tried applying an "all" transition to the repeated class and using ng-move  with no success.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/ng-repeat/move ?

Comment: @aet, this is for angular 1.1.5. The solution should probaly work with 1.2.x, I assume. Which is possible, but needs to be tested.

Comment: unfortunately, ng-move does not apply to this scenario. it only applies when items in the ng-repeat list are sorted or filtered. in this case, the item is being removed completely. Having said that - if I apply a filter first THEN remove the item, maybe I can "cheat" and get the benefits of ng-move. will try and update.

Comment: that did not work. applying the filter still resulted in the instant movement, not an smooth transition.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can achieve this by animating the `max-height` property. Check out this sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/k4sR3/8/

You will need to pick a sufficiently high value for `max-height` (in my sample, I used 90px).  When an item is initially being added, you want it to start off with 0 height (I'm also animating `left` to have the item slide in from the left, as well as `opacity`, but you can remove these if they don't jibe with what you're doing):

```
.repeated-item.ng-enter {
    -webkit-transition:0.5s linear all;
    -moz-transition:0.5s linear all;
    -o-transition:0.5s linear all;
    transition:0.5s linear all;
    max-height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    left: -50px;
}
```

Then, you set the final values for these properties in the `ng-enter-active` rule:

```
.repeated-item.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    max-height: 90px;
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
}
```

Item removal is a bit trickier, as you will need to use keyframe-based animations. Again, you want to animate `max-height`, but this time you want to start off at 90px and decrease it down to 0. As the animation runs, the item will shrink, and all the following items will slide up smoothly.

First, define the animation that you will be using:

```
@keyframes my_animation {
  from {
    max-height: 90px;
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
  }
  to {
    max-height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    left: -50px;
  }
}
```

(For brevity, I'm omitting the vendor-specific definitions here, `@-webkit-keyframes`, `@-moz-keyframes`, etc - check out the jsfiddle above for the full sample.)

Then, declare that you will be using this animation for `ng-leave` as follows:

```
.repeated-item.ng-leave {
  -webkit-animation:0.5s my_animation;
  -moz-animation:0.5s my_animation;
  -o-animation:0.5s my_animation;
  animation:0.5s my_animation;
}
```

---

**Basics**

In case anyone is struggling with figuring out how to get AngularJS animations to work at all, here's an abbreviated guide.

First, to enable animation support, you will need to include an additional file, `angular-animate.js`, *after* you load up `angular.js`. E.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular-1.2/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular-1.2/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

Next, you will need to load `ngAnimate` by adding it to the list of your module's dependencies (in the 2nd parameter):

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
```

Then, assign a class to your `ng-repeat` item. You will be using this class name to assign the animations. In my sample, I used `repeated-item` as the name:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" class="repeated-item">
```

Then, you define your animations in the CSS using the `repeated-item` class, as well as the special classes `ng-enter`, `ng-leave`, and `ng-move` that Angular adds to the item when it is being added, removed, or moved around.

The official documentation for AngularJS animations is here:

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations

Comment: This is great thank you! My problem was I was animating the leave/enter using transform:scaleY, which wasn't actually changing the element height, just its appearance of height. manipulating the height itself in the animation does the trick.

Comment: This is a great answer! I actually recorder a video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mRItxM1dHFA - to ask a better question and it was already solved by you! Regarding "how to setup an animation" --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21591860/how-to-use-ng-animate-in-angular-1-2 (very simple example)

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR:** Jank is bad, do animations with transform. Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Aides/Ly9p9kzu/) for css and demo.

---

#### Explanation

Note that animating `height`, `max-height`, `top`, ... is really bad performance wise because they cause reflows and thus jank (more information on [html5rocks|high-performance-animations](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/)).

There is however a method getting this type of animation using only transforms by utilizing the sibling selector.

When elements are added there is one reflow because of the new item, all items below are transformed up so they stay at the same position and then the transformation is removed for a smooth slide-in.

In reverse when elements are removed they are transformed to the new position for a smooth slide-out and when the element is finally removed there is again one reflow and the transform is removed instantly so they stay at their position (*this is also why it is important to only have `transition` set on `ng-animate`*).

Alternatively to the example you could also do a `transform: scaleY(0)` on the deleted item and only `transform: translateY()` the siblings.

#### Caveat

Note that this snippet has trouble when multiple elements are removed in quick succession (before the previous animation has completed).

This can be fixed by having an animation time faster than the time a user takes to delete another item or by doing some more work on the animation (out of scope of this answer).

#### Finally some code

**Note**: apparently SO breaks the demo with multiple deletes - check out the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Aides/Ly9p9kzu/) to see it in work.

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate'])
  .controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var self = this;
    
    self.items = [];
    
    var i = 65;
    for(; i < 72; i++)
    {
     self.items.push({ value: String.fromCharCode(i) });
    }
    
    self.addItem = function()
    {
     self.items.push({ value: String.fromCharCode(i) });
      i++;
    }
    
    self.removeItemAt = function(index)
    {
     self.items.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }])
```

```css
li
{
  height: 48px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}
li.ng-enter,
li.ng-enter ~ li {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
li.ng-enter.ng-enter-active,
li.ng-enter.ng-enter-active ~ li {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
li.ng-animate {
  z-index: -1;
}
li.ng-animate,
li.ng-animate ~ li {
  transition: transform 0.6s;
}
li.ng-leave,
li.ng-leave ~ li {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
li.ng-leave.ng-leave-active,
li.ng-leave.ng-leave-active ~ li {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.23/angular-animate.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="testCtrl as ctrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items" ng-bind="item.value">
      
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button ng-click="ctrl.addItem()">
  Add
  </button>
  <button ng-click="ctrl.removeItemAt(5)">
  Remove at 5
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Not bad. Unfortunately it doesn't handle varying item size. https://jsfiddle.net/Ly9p9kzu/5

Comment: Right, that would probably require some more JS work.

Comment: checked the fiddle, the bottom buttons are still jumping up after element removed