# Animate a div box with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

How can I animate a div-Box in AngularJS? I've tried several examples for my intention, but the animation doesn't work.

I want to create a method, if the user clicked on the button, then the search form displays in the view with a transition animation.

I know I have to create for my App module an .animation(). Can I create this in a Ctrl file or do I have to create it in a separate file?

```
<div ng-class="searchFormAnimation" ng-hide="searchFormHide">
...//search form
</div>

//In a separate panel is the button
<button type="button" class="btn" ng-click="btnSearch()">
  Search
</button>
```

Currently I'm using a scope variable in ng-hide which has a bool value. When I'm clicking on the button, then the variable gets the false value and the search form is showing. But I want to change this with Angulars animation and jQuery.

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle that we can play with? what sort of animation are you looking for?

Comment: Have you read [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21591860/how-to-use-ng-animate-in-angular-1-2)?

Comment: For DOM manipulation it's best to use directives and yes there are a lot of tutorials on how to use animations in AngularJS.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a JSFiddle. I have added the ngAnimate in my App Module and the script angular-animate.js in the index.html. I have taken the code sample from the angular docs site [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations) .The jQuery Part. But I want to use it in my method btnSearch() and when you click on the button then the animation will should fired.

Comment: @Mikey I have thought of a directive. In the angular docs are an abstract code sample how to create an animation directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a popular question, but I haven't seen everything put in one place. So here is my solution. Here we create custom directive and watch `animate-hide` attribute change and animate form based on it's value.

```js
var app = angular.module('animation', [
      
    ]).controller('MainController', function($scope) {
      $scope.hide = true;      
    }).directive('animateHide', function() {
      return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          
          scope.$watch(attrs.animateHide, function(val) {
            if(!val) {
              element.animate({
                "height": '100px',
                "opacity": "1"
              }, 300).show();
            } else {
              element.animate({
                "height": '0px',
                "opacity": "0"
              }, 100, function() {
                $(this).hide();
              });
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });
```

```css
form {
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.0/angular.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="animation">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
      <form animate-hide="hide"><input type="text" placeholder="Search"/></form>
      <button ng-click="hide = !hide">
        {{hide ? 'Show form' : 'Hide form'}}
      </button>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: many many thanks :) That is a perfect solution for my problem. Could I also use $on instead of $watch?

Comment: I've a question to your solution. When the page is starting the show-form-btn firstly goes up. How can I change this when I go to the page the btn moves only when I click on the button?

Comment: CSS `form {height:0; opacity:0;}`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this fiddle I made: http://jsfiddle.net/Lst8yudb/

```
angular.module("app", ['ngAnimate'])
.controller('mainctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.hide = false;
    $scope.hideForm = function () {
     $scope.hide=true;   
    }

});

.myform {
  -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
  transition:all linear 0.5s;
  background-color:red;
}

.myform.ng-hide {
   background-color:green;
  opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: Hej Mikey.. thanks for your example. I've taken the solution of ruslanas but I have one question to his example. When I'm loading the page, then the div box hides firstly, but I want that the box is already hidden.

Comment: Well if you really want to learn Angular you should not use Ruslanas answer. Not because it is bad, but it relies on jQuery too much. If you really want to master Angular animations you should go with ngAnimate. However, here is a fix to your problem http://jsfiddle.net/L8b0sfdL/.

Comment: Ok, that means in AngularJS I also need to work with angular modules like ngAnimate etc.? My question is why is it bad to work with jQuery in Angular code?